# Deleting nodes of a value in a Linked List in C++

Tags: c++

I'm practicing coding with some exercises from a website and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong in this implementation. Can someone please let me know where I'm going wrong in my code?

The function removeElements should delete all the elements with the given value from the list. I'm trying to obtain that by using another function called removeElement (singular), and running that until it isn't able to remove anything.

```
/**
* Definition for singly-linked list.
* struct ListNode {
*     int val;
*     ListNode *next;
*     ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(NULL) {}
* };
*/
class Solution {
public:
    bool removeElement(ListNode* head, int val) {
        if (!head)
            return false;

        ListNode* iterator = head;

        //deal with case where head is value to be deleted
        if (head->val == val) {
            head = head->next;
            delete iterator;
            if (head == NULL)
                delete head;
            return true;
        }

        //head didn't match so iterate through list
        while (iterator->next) {

            if (iterator->val == val) {
                ListNode* temp = iterator->next;
                delete iterator;
                iterator = temp;
                return true;
            }

            iterator = iterator->next;

        }//end while loop

        //case where tail is value
        if (iterator->val == val) {
            delete iterator;
            return true;
        }

        //otherwise return false
        return false;
    }//end function removeElement

    ListNode* removeElements(ListNode* head, int val) {

        //Keep calling removeElement until it returns false.
        while (removeElement(head, val)) {
        }

        return head;
    }
};
```

Comment: When deleting nodes that aren't `head` you never update the previous node's `next` pointer. Also what is `if (head == NULL)  delete head;` supposed to accomplish, it's basically a no-op.

Comment: Why did you comment out code that (it would be there) wouldn't  introduce compiler errors????

Comment: @CristiFati The `ListNode` type is probably defined elsewhere and is only here (commented out) to serve as a reminder of the layout of the class.

Comment: Hey, a solution has already (since we're chatting) been provided.

Answer (score 0):

Your `removeElement` method has a number of issues.  For one, if it removes the head, the caller has no way of knowing that it's list pointer has now been deleted.

Functions that manipulate a list like this should take a pointer reference like this... `bool removeElement(ListNode*& head, int val)`.  This way if the function changes the value of `head` the caller gets the new value back.

Next, when iterating across a singly linked list like this you should always maintain a pointer to the previous element...

```
ListNode* current{head}, prev{nullptr};
while (current) {
    // do something interesting
    prev = current;
    current = current->next;
}
```

In your case you want to remove nodes matching a given condition...

```
size_t removeElements(ListNode*& head, int val) {
    size_t removed{0};
    ListNode* current{ head }, prev{ nullptr };
    while (current) {
        // Use a nested while loop to check for the condition.  
        // This simplifies the conditions for the outer loop.
        while (current->val == val) {
            ++removed;
            ListNode* oldCurrent = current;
            current = current->next;
            // If this is the head element, update the head value for the caller
            if (oldCurrent == head) {
                head = current;
            }
            // Update the previous element in the list, if any
            if (prev) {
                prev->next = current;
            }
            // delete the removed element
            delete oldCurrent;
        }
        prev = current;
        current = current->next;
    }
    // return the number of element removed.
    return removed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the way do delete something from a linkedlist is this:

```
iter->prev->next = iter->next;
iter->next->prev = iter->prev;
delete iter;
```

This requires a doubly linked list though, meaning that each element points to the previous element.
If you don't want (or are not allowed to) add this, you can do something like this:

```
if(iter->next && iter->next->val == val ){
   node* deleteMe = iter->next;
   iter->next = iter->next->next;
   delete deleteMe;
}
```

Comment: Your singly-linked example can never delete the head.